# Run emacs elisp command with next word as argument

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I tell emacs to run my own script (which can be elisp too or something in Perl, BASH or whatever), and use the next word after the mouse cursor as argument, or maybe using a group of marked words? The output would be in another buffer.

Comment: "use next word" how - as the STDIN? as the command line argument? while Perl and bash are similar enough, elisp is far to different, you probably want to clearly specify one or the other, or maybe just re-phrase the question as, e.g., "how do pass the current word or selection to an elisp function".

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that takes the current region and displays it in a new buffer with a timestamp:

```
(defun date-stamp ()
(format-time-string " [%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y]"))

(defun extract-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (setq sel (buffer-substring start end))
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window (generate-new-buffer "*Command Output*"))
  (insert (concat (date-stamp) "\n" sel "\n")))
```